# How to remove quotes in between quotes using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

How can one remove the quotes in between quotes using Regex?

Say for the following string:

```
String sb233="\"DB\"|\"FB_\"ID\"|\"INV_\"ID\"|\"%T001\"|\"%T0\"16\"|\"OWNER_KEY\"|\"VEND_LABL\"|\"INV_KEY\"|\"FB_KEY\"|\"FB_AP\"P_AMT\"|...
```

The desired result:

```
String sb233="\"DB\"|\"FB_ID\"|\"INV_ID\"|\"%T001\"|\"%T016\"|\"OWNER_KEY\"|\"VEND_LABL\"|\"INV_KEY\"|\"FB_KEY\"|\"FB_AP\"P_AMT\"|...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(?<!\||^)\\"(?!\|)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC6iG4/1)

Input

```
\"DB\"|\"FB_\"ID\"|\"INV_\"ID\"|\"%T001\"|\"%T0\"16\"|\"OWNER_KEY\"|\"VEND_LABL\"|\"INV_KEY\"|\"FB_KEY\"|\"FB_AP\"P_AMT\"|...
```

Output:

```
\"DB\"|\"FB_ID\"|\"INV_ID\"|\"%T001\"|\"%T016\"|\"OWNER_KEY\"|\"VEND_LABL\"|\"INV_KEY\"|\"FB_KEY\"|\"FB_APP_AMT\"|...
```